# TFS Opening the Resolve Conflicts window programmatically

Tags: tfs, modal-dialog, programmatically-created, modeless

I'm using a VS extension that has the option of merging changesets. This extension opens the 'Resolve conflicts' window if conflicts are detect, allowing me to choose 'Merge automatically' (disabled), 'Merge in merge tool', 'Take source, 'Take target' etc.

The problem is that the window is modal. So if I want to view the merge in the default merge tool, it opens the comparison as a tabbed window behind the 'Resolve conflicts' window.

The code that opens the Resolve conflicts window is this:

```
try
{
    Assembly assres = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(ControlAddItemsExclude));
    var dlgResolveConflicts = assres.GetTypes().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "DialogResolveConflicts");
    dlgResolveConflicts.InvokeMember("ResolveConflicts", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static, null, null, new object[] { wrkspc, null, true, null });
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Utilities.OutputCommandString(ex.ToString());
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```

Can you guys help me open the 'Resolve conflicts' window in a modeless fashion, so I can interact with the merge comparison tool?

Kind regards,
Asser Fahrenholz

Comment: Visual studio 2013: 12.0.31101.00 Update 4

Comment: .NET Framework: 4.5.51650

Comment: I've also done extensive search on various MSDN forums, but the few questions that had similarities with mine went unanswered.

Comment: I tried going deeper into the assemblies and found out that the UIHost object that is used by 'ResolveConflicts' method is using the method 'ShowModalDialog()'. 
I'll try using UIHost.enableModeless() and see if that makes a difference

Answer (score 2):

I found a workaround:

When the modal window opens with manual conflicts needed, I open another VS2013, go to Pending Changes, go to Resolve Conflicts, do all the manual merges using the comparison tool. Once that is done, close the extra VS2013go back to the original VS2013 (with the modal window still open), press Refresh, close the window, continue.